# Automate subscription to Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose, there is a Kafka topic T having messages that could be categorized under type A, B, C, D, E.
We want to automate the process where someone could subscribe to topic T to read one or more type of messages and then push them to a new Kafka Topic.
Any suggestions?

Edit: Messages are not equally divided among the message types. Type A message could be 1% of Type B messages. Also, the type of messages could be 20 and change over time(type A to E are just for illustration).

Comment: You could partition the data by type and then have consumers reading one or multiple partitions of that topic.

Comment: Added more details as to why messages cannot be partitioned on Type

Comment: Partitions don't need to be equally weighted. And 20 partitions is no issue. Regarding the question, consumers only subscribe to topics, and optionally assigned partitions, not subsets of data types within the records. That being said, a consumer already would be reading all data you're sending, so what's the issue?

Comment: Every time we have to create a new kstream app whenever there is a requirement for consuming a new combination of message type. I am thinking if we could automate the process of creating kstream app by just mentioning the following:
* Input topic *type of messages to subscribe *output topic